# Do small business jets have HEPA filters?

Tags: air-conditioning, embraer-phenom

Do small business jets (Phenom 300 for example) have HEPA filters for recirculated air? Or don't they recirculate air at all?

Answer (score 2):

Embraer's own website confirms that their business jets can recirculate or draw fresh air, but HEPA filters don't seem to be an option until you get into the [Praetor size and above](https://executive.embraer.com/global/en/9155-achieve-fresh-clean-air-on-your-embraer-business-jet) -

> In addition, the now standard HEPA filter for the Praetor jets can
> capture 99.97% of bacteria, viruses, and fungi — further providing
> fresher, cleaner air inside the cabin. So when you fly on an Embraer
> business jet, you can breathe easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This information on the website seems a little confusing, since it does not specify if the recirculation exist in their smaller jets or if it's only a Praetor feature. It also seems a little strange to me to not filter at all the recirculated air.

Comment: @PedroGuimarães: I would be surprised if they didn’t have SOME kind of basic filter for recirculated air. It just won’t be rated for hazardous airborne particles like HEPA filters are.

Comment: Can you add a quote from their website and link to the relevant page(s).  That would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: Since HEPA filters are common, an after market kit may be readily available.  The filter just needs to be in the cabin airflow duct, with appropriate specs for flow.